# Printing string pyramid

Tags: python, loops

I want to print a pyramid pattern of string in python, but with user inputs of starting character and the no. of rows. I have wrote this code below so far,

```
c = input("Enter a character - ")  
def pattern(n):
    a = ord(c)
    for i in range(0, n):
            for j in range(0, i+1):
                ch = chr(a)
                print(ch, end=" ")
                a = a + 1
        print("\r")
n = int(input("Enter the no. of rows - "))
pattern(n)
```

But the output is:

```
Enter a character - A
Enter the no. of rows - 7
A 
B C 
D E F 
G H I J 
K L M N O 
P Q R S T U 
V W X Y Z [ \
```

Instead I want that after it's execution till the character 'z', it starts printing from character entered by the user for the same line only. And I want to make it work for both uppercase and lowercase alphabets.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem. You've made a statement, not a question. What debugging around `chr(a)` have you done?

Comment: And what if the starting character entered by the user is "E"? Do you go straight to "E" after "Z" or still go through ABCD..?

Comment: May I (kindly) point out that this is a triangle, not a pyramid ...

Comment: An idea might be to use the `string` library for your characters, then use modulo arithmetic to cycle back to the beginning once the last char is reached.

Answer (score 1):

so this sounded interesting so I tried working around this code and this is what I came up with. I edited your original code and tried making two separate functions for upper and lowercase. The thing is that the range of the ASCII codes had to be specified in the if block and I couldn't condition both ranges at once so I tried making separate functions.

```
c = input("Enter a character - ")  
def pyramid_caps(char):
    a= ord(c)
    b =ord(c)

    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, i+1):
            ch = chr(a)
            if a not in range(65,91):
                a=b
                continue
            print(ch, end=" ")
            a = a + 1

        print("\r")
    


def pyramid_lower(char):
    a= ord(c)
    b =ord(c)

    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, i+1):
            ch = chr(a)
            if a not in range(97,123):
                a=b
                continue
            print(ch, end=" ")
            a = a + 1

        print("\r")

            
    
n = int(input("Enter the no. of rows - "))

a=ord(c)
if a in range(65,90):
    pyramid_caps(a)

elif a in range(97,122):
    pyramid_lower(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could advance the current letter by 1, starting from c, until Z/z is reached, then reset to the initial letter:

```
def pattern(first,count):
    letter  = first
    for row in range(count):
        for _ in range(row+1):
            print(letter,end=" ")
            letter = first if letter in "Zz" else chr(ord(letter)+1)
        print("")
```

Sample runs:

```
Enter a character - A
Enter the no. of rows - 7
A 
B C 
D E F 
G H I J 
K L M N O 
P Q R S T U 
V W X Y Z A B 

Enter a character - p
Enter the no. of rows - 5
p 
q r 
s t u 
v w x y 
z p q r s
```

If you want an actual pyramid, you can add an indentation at the beginning of each row:

```
def pattern(first,count):
    letter  = first
    for row in range(count):
        print(" "*(count-row-1),end="") # indent for pyramid shape
        for _ in range(row+1):
            print(letter,end=" ")
            letter = first if letter in "Zz" else chr(ord(letter)+1)
        print("")

Enter a character - A
Enter the no. of rows - 7
      A 
     B C 
    D E F 
   G H I J 
  K L M N O 
 P Q R S T U 
V W X Y Z A B
```

Comment: Hey Alain, Thank You for helping me out with this and this worked perfectly fine.